# Excerpt – First Sentence & Read More

Tags: functions, excerpt

I am using this function to limit the excerpt to the first sentence...

```
function hello_first_sentence( $string ) {
 
    $sentence = preg_split( '/(\.|!|\?)\s/', $string, 2, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE );
    return $sentence['0'] . $sentence['1'];
 
} add_filter( 'get_the_excerpt', 'hello_first_sentence', 10, 1 );
```

However, for some reason, I am unable to add the "read more" after the excerpt... any help?

Comment: Where's the code with your attempt of what you're trying to do?

Comment: I have another function for that, but it doesn't work.function hello_excerpt_more($more) {
    global $post;
   return '... <span class="moretag">[+]</span>';
}
add_filter( 'excerpt_more', 'new_excerpt_more' );

Comment: It's useful to add specifically what you're trying to do and what you've tried to the question. 'It doesn't work' doesn't provide any information about what you actually want the outcome to be.

Comment: I want that after the excerpt, which was customized to show only the first sentence, to have "Read More".

Comment: Do you mean you want this: `return $sentence['0'] . $sentence['1'] . "... Read More";` ?

Comment: Yes, it works, thank you so much!!!

Comment: Great, I will add it as an answer

Comment: Thank you, already accepted!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To append strings in PHP use `.`, like:

```
return $sentence['0'] . $sentence['1'] . "... Read More";
```